# RubyMine quick doc on intellisense?

Tags: rubymine

Is it possible to show quick documentation about highlighted item on the intellisense menu in RubyMine like Eclipse does for Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`View` | `Quick Documentation` or it can be configured to appear automatically on explicit code completion in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `Code Completion`: `Autopopup documentation`.

Comment: I checked `Autopopup documentation` and it works. Thanks. But under View menu I can't see `Quick documentation` item?